# How to Get line number of a symbol in ELF using java code in Windows?

Tags: java, elf

I am using `org.eclipse.cdt.utils.elf` package to parse ELF file, but in that package, the `getLineNumber()` function has not been implemented.

Please help me in finding the line number of a symbol. I want this on Windows platform because anyway in Linux, we can use `nm` command to find that.